# How to centralize configurations across multiple node services?

Tags: node.js, config, configuration-files

There are multiple node services currently deployed and running through `pm2` in aws environment.

Difficulty(in terms of maintenance)  I see in my current code base is that each of these node services have a a separate configuration file (config\app.json) - Though, most of the properties in these configuration files are common for all the services, each of the property is mentioned in each individual service in code. If there is a change is any of these properties, I will have to modify the change in multiple places.

I would like to centralise the configurations across multiple node services. Is there a way to do that? Expectation is to have a centralised place for maintaining configurations. Any references would help.

Comment: If changes in configuration don't require restarting of an application, it is not a config, but a database.

Comment: Oh yes.. I dont have any problems with restarting the services after config changes, but mentioned that just in case if there is a way using which I could.. Main intention is to know about maintaining common config files across services.

Comment: There are plenty of standalone config management tools out there, and often orchestration tools has something built in. My point is if you write your application the way to handle runtime changes in the configuration, it becomes untrusted source, with all consequences.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your architecture is but if you do not mind creating a small library or microservice, which will just fetch you configurations from a small NoSQL database such as Redis which stores key-value pairs, then it will provide you with configurations at a centralized place.

Now the only configuration remains here is of redis which you can add while building the service by providing it's configuration as an environment variable using some thing like [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

Then in every service you'll have to make only one API call to fill up your config json in your case config/app.json